# Is polymorphism with sized traits possible in rust

Tags: rust, traits

I am using a library that exposes a trait which requires it to be `Sized`.

I am using an object that implements this trait, and am trying to create an array that include all those instances. With a non-sized trait I would use something like `Vec<Box<dyn MyNonSizedTrait>>`, but with the `Sized` trait it's impossible, the compiler complains with `the trait MySizedTrait cannot be made into an object`.

Is there any way to work around that?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```rust
trait A: Sized {
    fn do_something(&self);  
}
    
struct B;

impl A for B {
    fn do_something(&self){
        println!("This is B")
    }
}
    
struct C;
    
impl A for C {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        println!("This is C")
    }
}
    
    
fn my_do_something(d: &[Box<dyn A>]) {
    for i in d {
        i.do_something(); 
    }
}
    
fn main() {
    let mut d: Vec<Box<dyn A>> = Vec::new();
    d.push(Box::new(B));  
    d.push(Box::new(C)); 
    my_do_something(&d); 
}
```

Comment: The trait declaration explicitly denies any attempt at creating a trait object. Your only choice would be to use an enum or otherwise not use a trait object.

Comment: Why is the trait `Sized` to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dyn Trait` is always unsized by definition, because it allows the object behind it to have any size from `0` to `isize::MAX`.

To have a fixed-size object and polymorphism, use an `enum`. You can then add `impl` on the `enum` itself that dispatches calls to the variants. There are some [hacky crates](https://lib.rs/crates/enum_dispatch) that automate that.